# Swift gravity like the App "amazing Brick"

Tags: ios, swift, image, touch, gravity

I stuck at a point in my very first **swift** game (w/o SpriteKit etc.) and I really need your help.

I can't find an **algorithm for the gravity**, like in the App "amazing Brick" where the brick falls until the screen gets **touched** whereupon the brick **jumps either left or right - depends where the user touches the screen -** and falls again.

I want to create a similar game but just with an **UIImageView**.

I'd be really happy if someone has an answer.
Thanks to everyone! :D

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not clear what you're asking: do you need physical formulas for gravity? Or do you need to know how to move the UIImageView? Or both (in this case the question is too broad)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I need an algorithm to let my UIImageView jump up - either up left when I touch on the left side of the screen or up right when I touch on the right side - and then fall down like there where gravity and the same process when I click again and again. :)

Comment: you can use UIKit Dynamics,  have a look at https://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial

Comment: Oh great thank you but does this tutorial also explain how I can make the Image jump and how I can combine it with the gravity, like that the Image gets pulled down by the gravity after the jump?

Comment: Why are you not using SpriteKit if you want to make a game?. With SpriteKit this would be quite easy using impulses/forces and a SKScenes physics world gravity property.